# AJAX not firing after click yes to close bootstrap modal

Tags: ajax, yii, request

I have a link class to trigger a bootstrap modal every time one them is clicked.

```
     <a class="ptdel" href="#myModalx" role="link" data-toggle="modal" id="668" title='Delete'>x</a>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
         $(".ptdel").click(function(){ 

            var pcid = $(this).attr('id');
            if(pcid >= 40){
                $("#myModalxLabel").html("Delete?");  //adds to modal display text
            }

            $("#modalButtonxy").addClass("del_"+pcid); //adds class to yes button 

         });
     });
     </script>
```

With href="#myModalx" the modal pops up on click of the link. This already configured with Bootstrap.

This is my modal html code...

```
 <pre>
  my modal id="myModalx"
  my modal header id="modalHeadx" 

  my Yes button id="modalButtonxy" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="" onclick="yesDel(this);"

   my No button id="modalButtonxn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"

  </pre>
```

In my DOM ready code, I add a class to the yes button so that I can get the id of the link clicked.

It calls the JavaScript function below correctly...the alert is firing...but the problem is that it just won't fire off the ajax. I get no log on the console. I am using Yii for my php framework...and the url code here works in my other ajax calls.

```
 function yesDel(thecl){
 //    alert("works");    


            var modalclass = thecl.attr('class');
            var pid = modalclass.split("_").pop();
            //should return true or false back from request
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo CController::createUrl('/link/deletenow'); ?>',
                type: "POST",
                data: {linkid:pid,YII_CSRF_TOKEN: '<?php echo Yii::app()->request->csrfToken ?>'},
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data){  
                      if(!!data){

                         $("#flashmid").show();        
                         $("#flashmid").fadeIn(400).html('Delete Successful!');
                         $("#flashmid").fadeOut(400);  
                      }
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                   console.log(xhr.statusText);
                   console.log(textStatus);
                   console.log(error);
                   alert("error in deleting");
                }
            });   
  }
```

Please help I have troubleshoot all kinds of ways. The post actually works when I put it my periodic checks for database changes...but I need this to work on click and after user selects yes to delete.

Comment: Is the AJAX request being made?  Or is none of the code in the `$.ajax()` running at all?  In other words, if you use Firebug or similar, do you see the request to link/deletenow/ being made?  Also, since you're using the $.ajax shorthand, is jQuery available in the scope of the yesDel function?

Comment: @ernie No the request is not being made at all. None of the $.ajax() code is running. Yes, I use Firebug along and with FirePHP and I get no requests being made and I have the log in console code in place. Yes, jQuery is available in the scope of the yesDel function. I have also tried putting everything in the DOM ready function with the button having a .click() function and the $.ajax() within it, but still no request is being made.

Comment: it works now I changed thecl.attr('class'); to $(thecl).attr('class'); apparently this was stopping the flow. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of an old question.
But my problem was the same.

Maybe our problem was the data-dismiss in the button.
I think it could be that it relieves all the data inside of your form, but I'm not quite sure.

As for me this solution worked:

I hided the modal onclick with a jquery function, and everything worked fine.

```
$('#newBuildingSubmit').click(function(){

                                $('#newBuildingModal').modal('hide');

                               // AJAX CODE HERE

                            });
```

My Button looked like this:

```
<button type="submit" id="newBuildingSubmit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Speichern</button>
```

My button was wrapped inside of a modal.

Late answer, but could be a help to others facing the same issue :).